# Java/Spring Problem with @Service and @Autowired annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, javabeans

[spring 3.0.5]
[jboss 5.1]

I have several classes labeled as `@Service`, which implements thet same interface.

For example,

```
@Service(value="test1") 
public TestImpl1 implements Test {} 
@Service(value="test2") 
public TestImpl2 implements Test {}
```

Next, I have the following structure

```
public SomeClass { 
@Autowired 
@Qualifier("test1") 
Test test1; 
@Autowired 
@Qualifier("test2") 
Test test2;
```

I am getting an exception (at deployment)

```
10:36:58,277 ERROR [[/test-web]] Servlet /test-web threw load() 
exception 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
unique bean of type [pl.tests] is defined: expected single matching 
bean but found 2: [test1, test2] 
        at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doReso lveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java: 
796) 
        at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolv eDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java: 
703) 
        at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro cessor 
$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java: 
474)
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few options:

- Use `@Resource(name="test1")` in the injection point
- can use the `javax.inject.Qualifer` mechanism. In short - you define an annotation (`@Test`) and annotate the annotation with `@Qualifier`. Then use `@Autowired @Test` on the injection point.
- explicitly set qualifiers on the target bean. The docs say show only the xml version `<qualifier />`, but try adding `@Qualifier("test1")` on the service definition

[Here is the documentation about it](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Comment: Ok, I changed the code to something like. 

@Resource(name="test1")
public TestImpl1 implements Test {} 

@Resource(name="test2")
public TestImpl2 implements Test {} 

And in the target bean 

//but that is irrelevant to this issue
public SomeClass { 

@Autowired
@Qualifier("test1")
Test test1;
I am getting an exception (at deployment)
No matching bean of type [pl.Test] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: @user612925 by "injecetion point" I mean the point where you inject, not the service definition.

Comment: I did as you wrote right now. It seems that the problem is in the same declaration classes as services. Now i have code: @Service(value="test1") 
public TestImpl1 implements Test {} 
@Service(value="test2") 
public TestImpl2 implements Test {} 

Without point of injection. 

I have the same exception:
is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [test1, test2]

Comment: @user612925 you have it somewhere else, or you haven't cleaned your environment

Comment: @Bozho. I did not know how to do it, but I've learned. Is ok?

Comment: @user612925 yes, perfectly ok :)